# Duda sobre formulario y botón de paypal

Tags: php, html

Estoy pensando en hacer un formulario de inscripción, en la cual el usuario debe rellenar unos datos y después que pague por la inscripción. La idea que tenía es que el usuario rellene esos datos y cuando de al botón de pagar, realice el pago, y que introduzca esos datos en la base de datos. He visto que el botón paypal es un form.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Que debería hacer en este caso? Hacer un form para los datos y dentro de ese form, pegar el form del botón de paypal? Es necesario que los datos introducidos por el usuario lleguen a la base de datos cuando realice el pago y así se ahorraría un tiempo considerable de carga de trabajo.
Debe haber dos action, la introducción de datos y el del botón de paypal.

Un saludo

Comment: Estoy en lo mismo si encuentras respuesta sería muy util que la publicaras aqui mismo.

Comment: haber si nos ayuda alguien